# Func<> and memory leaks

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, callback, func

Given this code:-

```
public class ExpressionEvaluatorAce: ExpressionEvaluator
{
    readonly IContext target;

    public ExpressionEvaluatorAce(IContext target, string criteria, Func<string, object> missingPropertyCallback = null):
        base(missingPropertyCallback != null
            ? new EvaluatorContextDescriptorDefaultAce(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(target), missingPropertyCallback)
            : new EvaluatorContextDescriptorDefault(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(target)),
            CriteriaOperator.Parse(criteria))
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    // Since we are passing in the target context anyway, might as well store it and just use it
    public object Evaluate()
    {
        return Evaluate(target);
    }

    class EvaluatorContextDescriptorDefaultAce: EvaluatorContextDescriptorDefault
    {
        readonly PropertyDescriptorCollection properties;
        readonly Func<string, object> missingPropertyCallback;

        public EvaluatorContextDescriptorDefaultAce(PropertyDescriptorCollection properties, Func<string, object> missingPropertyCallback): base(properties)
        {
            this.properties = properties; // Copy since base.Properties is private!
            this.missingPropertyCallback = missingPropertyCallback;
        }

        public override object GetPropertyValue(object source, EvaluatorProperty propertyPath)
        {
            if (properties.Find(propertyPath.PropertyPath, true) == null)
            {
                return missingPropertyCallback(propertyPath.PropertyPath);
            }

            return base.GetPropertyValue(source, propertyPath);
        }
    }
}
```

and it being called like this:-

```
                result.Result = new ExpressionEvaluatorAce(context, reportSection.Condition,
                    missingProperty =>
                        {
                            if (missingProperty == "IgnoreSpec") return "XXX";

                            return null;
                        }
                    ).Evaluate();
```

will this cause a memory leak if this code is in a long-lived class?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  `Func` is just a delegate and there is no _subscription_ unlike `event`-related code which must be explicitly unsubscribed.

Comment: Thanks Micky - makes perfect sense when you put it like that! If you want to make it an Answer then I'll mark it Best answer so you get the score.

Comment: Not a problem good sir :)